# Prove: $\nabla_A \text{tr}\left(ABA^TC\right) = CAB + C^TAB^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Edit: there's another post asking the same thing, but it is not satisfactorily answered. At least not in what I believe is close to the simplest way.

---

Trying to prove property 3 below, in a "clean" way. That is using elementary definitions of linear algebra.

[image]

Attempt:

$$\nabla_A \text{tr}\left(ABA^TC\right) = \nabla_A \text{tr}\left(\left(A\right)BA^TC\right) \stackrel{(1)}{=} C^TAB^T$$

I think I'm missing some product rule stuff, but I don't see that defined anywhere in my text.

---

Edit2: Ahh, the second try is way wrong. Deleted it.

Comment: I guess that $A,B,C$ are rectangular matrices? Which scalar product are you taking?

Comment: I found a proof in this notes, it may help you:
https://web.stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/matrix_prop.pdf

Answer (score 0):

We will utilize the following identities

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B \right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TB) := A : B$$ or $$\left\langle A^T, B \right\rangle ={\rm tr}(AB) := A^T : B$$
- Following properties of Trace/Frobenius product 
  \begin{align}
  A : B C D 
   &= BCD : A \\
   &= A^T : (BCD)^T \\
   &= B^T A D^T  :  C  \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

We can obtain the differential first, and then the gradient.
\begin{align}
d \ {\rm tr }\left ( ABA^TC \right) 
&= d\left[A^T : BA^TC \right] \\
&= d\left[ (A^T)^T : (BA^TC)^T \right] \\
&= d\left[ A : C^T A B^T \right] \\
&= \left[ dA : C^T A B^T \right] + \left[ A : C^T \ dA \ B^T \right] \\
&= \left[ C^T A B^T : dA \right] + \left[ C A B : dA \right] \\
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\nabla_A \left[ {\rm tr }\left ( ABA^TC \right)  \right] = C^T A B^T + C A B \ .
\end{align}

Comment: Not in the same math I'm using now.